# I am trying to pass an array from my controller to the view section in <select>tag to display the options- not working

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, insert

I am trying to pass an array from my contoller to the view section in tag to display the options- not working
it was working before when there is no form validation and model to insert the values in database. If the form validation is removed from controller then form is directly submitting with null values showing error column_name cannot be null. What is wrong in my code? Please help me out!

**controller where iam passing the array to my view**

```
public function getskill()
{
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('give_my_best', 'Give my best', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('skills', 'Skills', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('have_done', 'Have done', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('work', 'I work', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
        $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
        $this->load->view('profile/editskill');
        $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');
    } else {
        $dataArr = array(

            "give_my_best" => ["On Stage", "Back Stage", "Services"],
            "OnStage"      => ["Actor", "Modelling", "Theatre Artist", "Dancer", "Singer", "Comedian", "Stand-up", "Voice-over", "Musician", "Composer", "Stunts", "Junior Artist", "Child Artist", "Compere/Host", "Reality show artist"],
            "BackStage"    => ["Producer", "Financer", "Director", "Story Writer", "Lyricist", "Dialogue writer", "Action", "Screenplay", "Cinematography", "Art Director", "Background score", "Editing", "Choreography", "Sound design", "Special Effects", "Costume design", "Make up artist", "Content writer"],
            "Services"     => ["Prop suppplier", "Technician", "Vendor"]


        );
        $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
        $this->load->view('profile/editskill', $dataArr);
        $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');

        $this->profile_model->insert_skill();
        redirect('profile/vabout');
    }
}
```

**Model to insert values in database**

```
public function insert_skill() {
    $data = array(
        'give_my_best' => $this->input->post('give_my_best'),
        'occupation' => $this->input->post('skills'),
        'have_done' => $this->input->post('have_done'),
        'work' => $this->input->post('work')
    );
    $this->db->insert('profiles',$data);
}
```

**View: This is the form where iam passing the array**

```
<form method="post" id="editskill" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/getskill" name="editskill">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 text-right">I give my best:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="chosen-select"
                    name="give_my_best"
                    data-placeholder="Give best"
                    tabindex="6"
                    id=""
                    multiple="multiple">
                <?php foreach($give_my_best as $value) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 text-right">Skills:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="chosen-select" name="skills" data-placeholder="Skills" tabindex="6" id=""
                    multiple="multiple">
                <optgroup label="On Stage">
                    <?php foreach($OnStage as $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Back Stage">
                    <?php foreach($BackStage as $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Services">
                    <?php foreach($Services as $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    </div> <!-- Angular JS ends here -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary col-md-7 col-md-offset-3 text-right"
                id="submit"
                value="submit"
                name="submit">Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: if you want to redirect to another page than why r you loading view

Comment: Where are the inputs/selects for 'have_done' and 'work' ?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you loading the views and then also redirecting it to another

```
$this->load->view('templates/pheader');
$this->load->view('profile/editskill', $dataArr);
$this->load->view('templates/pfooter');

$this->profile_model->insert_skill(); //put this line before you load the views
redirect('profile/vabout'); //you can remove this line
```

So rearrange these line as

```
$this->profile_model->insert_skill();
$this->load->view('templates/pheader');
$this->load->view('profile/editskill', $dataArr);
$this->load->view('templates/pfooter');
```

And you don't need to use two different functions inside the controller to submit a form, You can do it with a single function and you just need to check if form submitted then #insert code else show the normal view